# Mapping JSON response to corresponding POJO

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have problem with my project, when getting response from json.

This is my JSON Structure

```
{
"RC": "00",
"FakturPengajuan": "PO201901310000000007",
"Plafond": "1,000,000.00",
"Pokok": "500,000.00",
"Bunga": "10,000.00",
"TotalBayar": "510,000.00",
"JT": {
    "1": {
        "Ke": 1,
        "JatuhTempo": "28 Februari 2019",
        "Pokok": "500,000.00",
        "Bunga": "10,000.00",
        "Jumlah": "510,000.00",
        "BakiDebet": "500,000.00"
    },
    "2": {
        "Ke": 2,
        "JatuhTempo": "31 Maret 2019",
        "Pokok": "500,000.00",
        "Bunga": "10,000.00",
        "Jumlah": "510,000.00",
        "BakiDebet": "0.00"
    }
}
```

}

This is my response code

```
@Override
        public void onFinish(String cResponse) {
            String cError = null;
            if (cResponse != null){
                try{
                    Response response = gson.fromJson(cResponse,Response.class);
                    if (response != null && response.getRC() != null){
                        if (response.getRC().equals("00")){



                        }else cError = response.getMSG();
                    }else{
                        cError = "Error";
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    cError = "Error" + e.getMessage();
                    FuncApp.showLog("Response " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }else cError = "Gagal";
            if (cError != null)
                new FuncApp.OkNoDialog(getActivity(),"Gagal Aktivasi",cError ,null,"OK").setOnFinish(new FuncApp.OkNoDialog.ButtonClick() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(Boolean isOKButton) {

                    }
                });

            funcApp.closeProgresDialog();
        }
```

and this is my response getter and setter, not all, just all variable that I use.

```
public class Response {
private String RC;
private String FakturPengajuan, Plafond, Pokok, Bunga, TotalBayar;
private String[] JT;

public Response(){}
  }
```

I got this error when getting response, what should the code be?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Comment: When posting code or in this case JSON data please [format it as text](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) so that anyone trying to help can easily make use of it when recreating your problem.

Comment: edited. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POJO class `Response` has some invalid structure fields `JT` is `Map` not an array and you should have getters and setters

```
public class Response {
private String RC;
private String FakturPengajuan, Plafond, Pokok, Bunga, TotalBayar;
private Map<String,MapValue> JT;

 public Response(){}
  }
```

**Map value class**

```
public class MapValue {

 private int Ke;
 private String JatuhTempo;
 private String Pokok;
 private String Bunga;
 private String Jumlah;
 private String BakiDebet;

 }
```

Comment: I have done getters and setters in Response Class, and I have done changing JT to Map, but still can't with same error

Comment: Update error with stacktrace and also verify the json again @RPH